# Add a way to hide vote history rows on timelines

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools, timeline

On [some timelines](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/686995/timeline), mostly on highly-voted, older posts, the vote history rows get in the way of events I'm actually interested​ in.

Could we have a way to toggle these rows from being displayed?

Comment: Behold the wonders of jQuery: `$("tr[data-eventtype='voteaggregate']").hide()`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but looking at the tags here, in what way is this related to the diamond moderator tools?  I can see the timeline on sites where I'm not a mod – what am I missing?

Comment: @Nathaniel Since the timeline (in its current form) was a moderator-only tool for a long time, and since it's mostly used by moderators doing moderation things, I believe it makes sense for this to be classified as an enhancement to moderator tools.

Comment: @undo Makes sense; thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Before this feature gets implemented, you can use [a userscript I wrote](https://stackapps.com/q/7042/38449)—it adds a "Toggle vote history" button to the timeline, which toggles visibility of vote events.

[image]